# How to default to "Y" with Zsh's read -q

Tags: input, zsh

For some reason this function always gets "n" as the input when I hit <kbd>return</kbd>, even though I would expect it to get an empty string or maybe a newline character.  I would expect it to get just about anything EXCEPT "n"

```
function readtest() {-
  local YorN  # this ensures there is no left-over value in YorN
  #echo -ne "Go ahead?  [Y/n]"; read -q YorN  # this version the same result as the next line
  read -q "YorN?Go ahead?  [Y/n]"
  [[ "$YorN" = "\n" ]] && echo "Matched Newline" # I don't really expect this to return true: it's just here to test
  [[ "$YorN" != "n" ]] && echo "Do the thing!" # I expect this test to return true... this is the weird thing, and central to my question
  echo "## $YorN ##"  # I always get "## n ##"
}
```

Why is the value of `YorN` "n"???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when using the option `-q`. Here is the relevant part of the [ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read):

> ```
> read [ -rszpqAclneE ] [ -t [ num ] ] [ -k [ num ] ] [ -d delim ]
>      [ -u n ] [ name[?prompt] ] [ name ... ]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> `-q`
>
> Read only one character from the terminal and set *name* to ‘`y`’ if this character was ‘`y`’ or ‘`Y`’ and to ‘`n`’ otherwise. With this flag set the return status is zero only if the character was ‘`y`’ or ‘`Y`’. This option may be used with a timeout (see `-t`); if the read times out, or encounters end of file, status 2 is returned. Input is read from the terminal unless one of `-u` or `-p` is present. This option may also be used within zle widgets.

If you want to have the opposite behavior, i.e. only assume a negative answer if you entered either ‘n’ or ‘N’ and a positive answer otherwise, you can use the option `-k 1`:

```
function readtest {
    local YorN
    read -q "YorN?Go ahead? [Y/n]"
    if [[ ${(U)YorN} == "N" ]] ; then 
        echo "Don't do the thing!"
    else
        echo "Go ahead!" 
    fi
}
```

---

Another option would be to invert the question:

```
read -q "YorN? Stop here? [y/N]"
```

Comment: Ugh—I can't believe I missed that.  I was reading `man zshbuiltins` for other options, but I failed to double-check my understanding of how `-q` worked...